# PHP image uploader not working with Capital JPG extension

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, jpeg

Thanks in advance.

I have a php image uploader that I built, which is working just fine.  However I tried uploading a .JPG extension image and it did not work.  Please note I mean capital JPG and not lowercase jpg.  .png, .jpg, .gif all work fine and get uploaded, the thumbnails are created and what not.  It is the capital .JPG that isn't working for some reason.  See my code below.  Is it a different mime type?

The queries (which I removed for security purposes) work just fine.  The information is stored.  It is the moving of the file and thumbnail to the correct folders that isn't happening due to the capital .JPG extension.  Any help would be great, I did some research and tried the Apache add type JPG and that did not work.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $getcatid = mysql_query('"query here"');
    $rescatid = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcatid);
    $catid = $rescatid['catid'];

    if ((($_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/png") || 
        ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/jpeg") ||
        ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES['file']['size'] < 2097152))
    {

        if (file_exists("location here".time().'_'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo '<div class="error">'.$_FILES["file"]["name"].' already exists</div>'; 

            }
        else
            {

                    $filename = time().'_'.$_FILES['file']['name'];  
                    $source = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
                    $target = 'location here'.$filename;  

                    move_uploaded_file($source, $target); 

                    createThumbnail($filename);  

                $date = time();
                $store = '"query here"';';

                mysql_query ($store);

                echo '<div class="success">Image added</div>';

            }
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<div class="error">Invalid file, only jpg, jpeg, or png file types allowed</div>';
    }

}

if(isset($_POST['multisubmit']))
{

    $getcatid = mysql_query('"query here"');
    $rescatid = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcatid);
    $catid = $rescatid['catid'];


    for($i=0;$i< count($_FILES['multifile']['type']);$i++)
    {

        if ((($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$i] == "image/png") || 
        ($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$i] == "image/jpeg") || 
        ($_FILES['multifile']['type'][$i] == "image/pjpeg")) && 
        ($_FILES['multifile']['size'][$i] < 2097152))
        {

            $filename = time().'_'.$_FILES['multifile']['name'][$i]; 
            $source = $_FILES['multifile']['tmp_name'];   
            $target = 'location here'.$filename;  

            if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['multifile']['tmp_name'][$i],$target))
            {
                createThumbnail($filename);  

                $date = time();
                $store = '"query here"';';

                mysql_query ($store);

                echo '<div class="success">Image: '.$filename.' added, view individual album to edit image descriptions</div>';
            } 
            else
            {
            echo '<div class="error">Invalid file'.$filename.', only jpg, jpeg, or png file types allowed</div>';
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Thumbnail function if it helps:

```
function createThumbnail($filename) {  
$final_width_of_image = 160;  
$path_to_image_directory = 'path here';  
$path_to_thumbs_directory = 'path here';

if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {  
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);  
} else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {  
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);  
} else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {  
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);  
}  

$ox = imagesx($im);  
$oy = imagesy($im);  

$nx = $final_width_of_image;  
$ny = floor($oy * ($final_width_of_image / $ox));  

$nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);  

imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);  

if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {  
  if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {  
       die("There was a problem. Please try again!");  
  }  
   }  

imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename, 100);  

}
```

Comment: have you tried echoing the mime type and die()'ing?

Comment: Yes, here is the echo of the file type when uploading a .JPG image: image/jpeg

Comment: Can you post your create thumbnail function? If you everything works fine except the thumbnail creation and moving, the problem should be there.

Comment: When you say "It is the moving of the file and thumbnail to the correct folders that isn't happening.", that means you could locate the problem to the `move_uploaded_file($source, $target);` part of the code, right? Also, you might want to store the value of `time()` in a variable and use the variable instead. In your code, `if (file_exists("location here".time().'_'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]))` and later `$filename = time().'_'.$_FILES['file']['name']; ` could have different `time()` value.

Comment: Please read full question.  The upload works perfectly for .jpg .png and .gif.  It moves the files, creates the thumbnails and stores the image in the correct uploads folder.  it is the .JPG extension that is not working for some reason.  Why would that be?  I will post the thumbnail function.

Comment: Your thumbnail function is looking specifically for 'jpg' and other extensions.  'JPG' will not match.  That's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your thumbnail code:

```
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename))
```

That will only match lowercase 'jpg'.  If you want to match upper or lowercase, you can add the `/i` flag for case-insensitivity:

```
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/i', $filename))
```