# Problem with watermark .JPG images in php

Tags: php, file-upload, watermark

I use this code for watermark photos with PHP uploads. If the photo is a `.jpg` all is well. If `.JPG` (capitalized) then this stops working:

```
 $targetFilePath = $folderPath . $file_name; 
 $watermarkImg = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkImagePath); 

 switch($fileType){ 
     case 'jpg': 
         $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath); 
         break;                         
     case 'jpeg': 
         $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath); 
         break; 
     case 'png': 
         $im = imagecreatefrompng($targetFilePath); 
         break; 
     default: 
         $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath); 
 } 

 $marge_right = 1; 
 $marge_bottom = 1; 

 $sx = imagesx($watermarkImg); 
 $sy = imagesy($watermarkImg); 

 imagecopy($im, $watermarkImg, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($watermarkImg), imagesy($watermarkImg)); 

 imagejpeg($im, $targetFilePath,70); 
 imagedestroy($im);
```

I tried adding this, but it didn't help:

```
 case 'JPG': 
     $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath); 
     break;
```

Please help.

Comment: I assume your $fileType is just a string. Try switch(strtolower($fileType)){

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it doesn't work. All the same, no watermark on .JPG

Comment: Perhaps the underlying function does not expect a file with extension 'JPG' ?

Answer (score 0):

Since strtolower  does not work.
Use if/else condition like this way_

```
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/i', $file_name)) {  
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath);  
} else if (preg_match('/[.](jpeg)$/i', $file_name)) {  
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFilePath);  
} else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/i', $file_name)) {  
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($targetFilePath);  
}
```

Comment: Please read this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273804/php-image-uploader-not-working-with-capital-jpg-extension

Comment: I read. I have upload, resize and watermark files in my code. Upload and resize .JPG files work. Only a watermark does not.